# Setting up an interceptor that uses setState before children mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im following a React course, and in that course the teacher has built a higher order component to handle http errors.

The code they end up with is this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal';
import Aux from '../Aux/Aux';

const withErrorHandler = ( WrappedComponent, axios ) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            error: null
        }

        componentWillMount () {
            this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({error: null});
                return req;
            });
            this.resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
                this.setState({error: error});
            });
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            axios.interceptors.request.eject(this.reqInterceptor);
            axios.interceptors.response.eject(this.resInterceptor);
        }

        errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
            this.setState({error: null});
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <Aux>
                    <Modal 
                        show={this.state.error}
                        modalClosed={this.errorConfirmedHandler}>
                        {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
                    </Modal>
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                </Aux>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default withErrorHandler;
```

He does mention that `componentWillMount()` will be depreciated so to use `constructor()` to set up the interceptors for the same effect.

The part I don't understand is how this works for him and not for me, as far as I understand, it shouldn't work.
`WrappedComponent` executes an `axios` get request on its `ComponentDidMount()` method, that means that the `reqInterceptor` and `resInterceptor` will run before this component is mounted and s`etState` is available.
Am I misunderstanding something on how this is supposed to work? Did something change between React 16.0.0 and now that alters how it works?

Comment: Instead of `componentWillMount` you can use `componentDidMount` and that's fine.  But I'm a little bit confused by this code.  Shouldn't we be passing `axios` down to `WrappedComponent`?

Comment: I guess we are just assuming that `WrappedComponent` will use the same instance of `axios` as the one that we modified, but I don't like that assumption.

Comment: I can write up an answer but all the info you need is in [this doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).  In particular "UNSAFE_componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead for initializing state. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead."